# Sequelize Count and Group Nested Include

Tags: sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have got a few sql tables as

```
export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
return sequelize.define('teacher', {
    tagline: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    modeOfPayment: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    modeOfSession: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    preferredTimeZones: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    titleForSessions: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    availableForWork: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
});
};

export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define('skill', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });
};

export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
return sequelize.define('category', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
});
};
```

Here is the model relation between them

```
Teacher.belongsToMany(Skill, {
    through: 'skill_teacher',
});
Skill.belongsToMany(Teacher, {
    through: 'skill_teacher',
});

Category.hasMany(Skill);
Skill.belongsTo(Category);
```

Earlier I needed to query count of teachers in each skill, here's my controller for that

```
// @desc Get skill count for each skill
// @route GET /api/skills/count
// @access Public
const getSkillCount = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const skills = await Skill.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'name',
                [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('teachers.id')), 'teacherCount'],
            ],
            include: [{ attributes: [], model: Teacher }],
            group: ['skill.id'],
        });
        res.json(skills);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500);
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
});
```

Now, the skills are grouped in categories. So I wanna query a list of skills having their own teacher count grouped in their own categories, which category also having a skillCount column. I tried this but it is not giving my desired results

```
// @desc Get category and their skills counts
// @route GET /api/categories/skills/count
// @access Public
const getCategorySkillCounts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const categories = await Category.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'name',
                [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('skills.id')), 'skillCount'],
            ],
            include: {
                model: Skill,
                include: [{ model: Teacher }],
                attributes: [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('teachers.id')), 'teacherCount'],
                ],
                group: ['skill.id'],
            },
            group: ['category.id'],
        });

        res.json(categories);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500);
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
});
```